# Can I use join instead of a subquery which returns 1 row?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT p1.*,
       (select guid
        from wp_posts p2
        where p2.post_parent = p1.id
        ORDER by p2.id DESC
        LIMIT 1) as post_image
from wp_posts p1
where p1.post_status = 'publish' and
      p1.post_type = 'post'
order by p1.id DESC limit 4
```

I want to make the same query but using `join` *(instead of subquery)*. Is it possible ?

Comment: Can you edit to include some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Just for information, these type of subqueries are called Scalar Subqueries. A subquery is a scalar subquery that returns a single value. [Scalar Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/scalar-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try rewriting using a series of extra joins:

```
SELECT
    p1.*,
    COALESCE(t2.guid, 'NA') AS post_image
FROM wp_posts p1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT post_parent, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM wp_posts
    GROUP BY post_parent
) t1
    ON p1.id = t2.post_parent
LEFT JOIN wp_posts t2
    ON t1.max_id = t2.id
WHERE p1.post_status = 'publish' AND p1.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY p1.id DESC
LIMIT 4;
```

The logic behind the above refactor is, by observation, that your current subquery is returning the record, for each value of `post_parent`, having the max value of `id`.  So, we can join to a subquery which finds the max `id` value for each `post_parent` group.  Then, we need to join again to `wp_posts` to bring in the `guid` value for that max `id` row.

Comment: Please explain  ON p1.id = t2.post_parent
LEFT JOIN wp_posts t2

Comment: @ItiTyagi I added a description, hopefully that clears things up for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT p1.*, p2.guid FROM 
wp_posts as p1 
JOIN wp_post AS p2 ON  p2.post_parent = p1.id 
AND p1.post_status = 'publish' AND p1.post_type = 'post'
ORDER by p1.id DESC limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT p1.*       
from wp_posts p1
left outer join(select guid
        from wp_posts 
        where p2.post_parent = p1.id
        ORDER by p2.id DESC
        LIMIT 1) as post_image
where p1.post_status = 'publish' and
      p1.post_type = 'post'
order by p1.id DESC limit 4
```

Comment: Where is `post_image` in your `select` statement?